# Building/calling librsync on Windows from Delphi 2010

Tags: dll, diff, delphi-2010, delta, librsync

I'm currently using the **rdiff** windows port from my **delphi 2010** application to calculate delta/signature for remote delta/diff

I'm trying to explore the possibility of using the **librsync** library instead of **rdiff**, I googled & read a lot, I found these files (can be found/installed using cygwin - librsync-dev-0.9.7-3):

```
cygrsync-1.dll
librsync.a
librsync.dll.a
librsync.la
```

However, it's not clear **at all** how to call this dll (assuming it's even possible!)

Anyone knows how to call the librsync/cygrsync-1.dll from Delphi 2010?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is a great idea. Linking to a cygwin based DLL will also require you to link to cygwin. You ought to be able to find a native port of librsync (most likely built with mingw) and then you need a header translation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: **rdiff.exe** already requires **cygwin-1.dll**, so I'm going to ship it anyway if I keep using it. Also, native dll or not, I'll need header translation in both cases (which is precisely what I'm trying to find, but I'm completely cluless)

Comment: And you are happy with the terms of the GPL meaning that you will have license your app under the GPL too, or something compatible with GPL.

Comment: As for the header translation you need to make a file like Windows.pas that defines the appropriate records/structs and imports the necessary functions from the DLL. Or find one that has already been made for Delphi.

Comment: Actually that's one of the reasons why I want to switch to librsync (whose license is LGPL). As for the headers translation, I **really** googled a lot but couldn't find any pascal translation, and my knowledge in C is next to zero to do that myself, that's why I'm asking if someone has done it before (or can give some insights on this)

Comment: I think the JEDI website and Rudy Velthuis' blog have advice on header translations. Linking to cygwin makes you code GPL. You'll need to do what I said and build with mingw or some other compiler. Cygwin is a no go for you.

Comment: Wonderful :( Thanks for the warning, David! I didn't realize I had to  GPL my app in order to use the cygwin DLL. This makes my task even harder...

Comment: @Gdhami: you should probably install msys which will certainely compile librsync (and with no dependency on cygwin), and you could try h2pas (from the freepascal project) to get a pascal unit, the .h is pretty trivial it could work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile and build librsync using visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185936/how-to-compile-and-build-librsync-using-visual-studio-2010)